# ¿Cómo guardar registros en pascal? en lazarus

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal, lazarus

Estoy tratando de guardar un `registro` en un archivo de texto, pero soy nuevo en Pascal y realmente no entiendo cómo hacer este proceso. Me explico:

Tengo un formulario donde quiero agregar 5 alumnos, en el `record` la información se llena por alumno y con un `array` trato de guardar la información de 5 alumnos y separarla por equipos (hasta 10 equipos). Entiendo cómo hacer ese `registro`, revisarlo y asignarle valor a los campos, mi problema es que no sé cómo guardarlo correctamente.

No sé si un archivo de texto puede contener un `array` que tenga un `registro` dentro con campos de varios tipos. Realmente agradecería su orientación, acabo de comenzar en Pascal.

Esto es lo que he hecho:

```
type
  alumnos = record
    nombre,apellido:string[60];
    id,tiempoA,tiempoB,tiempoT,promedio,lapsoA,lapsoB,lapsoC:integer;
  end;

var
  datos: array[1..5]of alumnos;

procedure TForm3.ingresarEquipoClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  tA,tB,lA,lB,lC,prom:integer;
begin
  if (nombre1.text<>'') and (apellido1.text<>'') and (tiempoA1.text<>'') and
     (tiempoB1.text<>'') and (lapsoA1.text<>'') and (lapsoB1.text<>'') and
     (lapsoC1.text<>'') then
  begin
    AssignFile(tDatos,'datos.txt');
    rewrite(tDatos);

    {Guardo la informacion de un estudiante por ahora}

    tA:=StrToInt(tiempoA1.text);
    tB:=StrToInt(tiempoB1.text);
    lA:=StrToInt(lapsoA1.text);
    lB:=StrToInt(lapsoB1.text);
    lC:=StrToInt(lapsoC1.text);

    datos[1].id:=1;
    datos[1].nombre:=nombre1.text;
    datos[1].apellido:=apellido1.text;
    datos[1].tiempoA:=tA;
    datos[1].tiempoB:=tB;
    datos[1].tiempoT:=tA+tB;
    datos[1].lapsoA:=lA;
    datos[1].lapsoB:=lB;
    datos[1].lapsoC:=lC;

    write(tDatos,datos);
    closeFile(tDatos);

  end
else
  begin
    ShowMessage('Insert content');
  end;
end;
```

Me suelta este error:

> unit3.pas (147,24) Error: Incompatible types: got "Array [1..5] Of alumnos" expected "alumnos".

Y si cambio `write(tDatos,datos)` por `write(tDatos,alumnos)`, me dice:

> unit3.pas (147,26) Error: Can't read or write variables of this type

Comment: ¿de que tipo es la variable tDatos?

Comment: En Pascal existen dos tipos de archivos los de texto y los binarios, me parece que tu labor sería más fácil si usas archivos binarios y no de texto.

Comment: No has incluido la declaración de la variable `tDatos` en tu código, por lo que dudo que, con el código que muestras, obtengas el error que dices... ya que la variable no está declarada. Por favor, incluye su declaración.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es un fichero para almacenar `alumnos`, debes definirlo como tal, así que la definición del registro podría ser de la siguiente manera:

```
  tDatos:File of alumnos;
```

Para almacenar los alumnos deberás hacerlo de uno en uno. Puedes usar un bucle y recorrerlo. En tu ejemplo, que estás rellenando el primer elemento del array, puedes almacenarlo con:

```
write(tDatos, datos[1]);
```

Con esto, tu código funcionará y generará un fichero con el primer elemento del array.